# How to fix the error: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "created_at" is ambiguous

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

This issue started all of a sudden. Never seen before. Error was raised at below code.

I tried to replace @events.group_by_day(:created_at) with "@events.created_at" and reloaded console. but nothing seems to work.

```
...
<%= line_chart @events.group(:category_id).group_by_day(:created_at).count, id: 'event_line_chart' %>
...
```

application.html.erb:

```
...
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/authy-forms.css/2.2/form.authy.min.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/authy-forms.js/2.2/form.authy.min.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 ...
```

Expected to show the page but getting above error. Please help me with this